# Change owner in a case insert trigger does not run from Community

Tags: trigger, community, lightning-community, guest-user

I have a lightning component in a community that inserts a new case.

The case object has a before-insert trigger that changes the case ownerId.

I get an error `INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY` when this code runs from the community context (the community guest user).

I believe that this error is because I need read access on the User object which I cannot give the community guest user.

This is my trigger code (for an example):

```
trigger Case_Trigger on Case (before insert, before update, after insert, after update) { 
    if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert) {    
        Trigger.new[0].OwnerId= 'myUserId';
    }
}
```

**Question**

If there a way to give acees to the community guest user (or profile) for changing the ownerId of a case?

Comment: Then why not you are using assignment rule

Comment: Actually the case trigger is very very big with a lot of code inside. This ownership change is a very specific case which I need to change the ownership via code in the trigger

Comment: I'm afraid that you can do in same record which part of trigger.new; create a new instance like Case c = new Case(Id=trigger.new[0].Id, OwnerId='005....'); and update it. mind recursion.

Comment: But I do not want to create another case - this will trigger a lot of other stuff for me and is not something I want or need to deal with - it is not an option for me. But I do ask - this is not possible to do?

Comment: It iwll not create another case, it will update

Comment: I have tried that, I get an error: `UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record`. also I don't understand this solution - how can I update a record from within the `before insert` trigger of this record. Anyway - I cannot get this working.